# Why a virtual machine (VM) is used to run and deploy Hadoop cluster and its modules?

Tags: hadoop, virtual-machine

I am new to Hadoop and don't know the reason why a virtual machine (VM) is used to run and deploy Hadoop cluster and its modules?
Can we not use Hadoop through the local Linux/Unix system

Comment: Please link to the deployment instructions you are referring to.

Comment: It's actually strongly encouraged to use physical hardware for Hadoop... Your question seems to be  more about why virtualize than anything specific  about Hadoop

Comment: @Thilo: There are npdeployment instructions. I watched a couple of tutorials and everyone was either using Sandbox or Cloudera, so I was wondering why do we necessarily need to use a VM.

Comment: @cricket_007: Hadoop physical hardware requirements can be met by having local machines as well. If you can answer in terms of Hadoop, that would be great

Comment: VMs can be  local. I don't get your point, but it comes down to time and money in most cases. **Tutorials** use the sandbox or quickstart VM to get started, but large installs are definitely physical

Answer (score 0):

> the reason why a virtual machine (VM) is used to run and deploy Hadoop cluster and its modules

Because lots of data centers have more virtual space than physical space. Thousands of servers can run on hundreds of machines (approximately). That's what any Hadoop Cluster in the cloud would be - a bunch of virtualized machines.

Because some companies just want a small, cheap proof of concept that Haddon will work within their ecosystem of existing software.

Because it's makes an easy demo to boot up a VM rather than carry around several machines.

etc...

Anyways, I'd say it's strongly encouraged to use physical hardware, but that costs time and resources to maintain in terms of money and dealing with hardware failures and keeping software patched between Hadoop and the OS. Primarily you'd want to be able to pick and choose hardware that suits your use cases. Lots of storage for a "data lake" or lots of memory for fast processing. Mix in some SSD for fast caching...

Sure, VMs let you dynamically allocate some of those items, but when a disk or memory stick goes corrupt, it affects all VMs on one machine rather than one server